# Adding a step or bootstrap action in EMR 3.10 to copy a file from local to s3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR 3.10 for my purpose where I want to copy a file from local to Amazon S3...I am using "script-runner.jar" where in the arguments,I am mentioning a command in the arguments **sudo aws s3 cp /home/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml s3://testbucket/myfolder/--recursive** ....But the step is getting failed & throwing the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Local file does not exist.
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.fetchFile(ScriptRunner.java:30)
at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.scriptrunner.ScriptRunner.main(ScriptRunner.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

What do I need to do in the step so that it copies the file from local to Amazon S3 ?? Also I want to raise few questions ??
1 ) If I need to use "command-runner.jar",how can I use command-runner in EMR 3.10 ??
2) How can I do the copying task using Bootstrap action ??

Thank You

Comment: If this activity happens before the hadoop installation, the conf file will not exists and you will get file not found exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to perform this copy in a bootstrap action, note that 
the hadoop user does not exist until after the bootstrapping phase has completed.

That would explain the error.

Doing the copy operation as an EMR Step should work as hadoop is installed by that point.

See the lifecycle of an EMR for more details: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-overview.html#emr-overview-cluster-lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the program is unable to find the local file

```
/home/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

Does the file exists?

You could also try using a nice tool called [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd)

Comment: Well the file exists at that location.. I want to copy the file when I launch EMR so that the file will get copied through either step or bootstrap action?? will I be able to use "s3cmd put --recursive dir1 s3://s3tools-demo/some/path/" command in step of EMR 3.10 cluster ??